# How to Convert JSON Object to PDF and send it through mail using only client side coding?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am generating JSON object and i want to convert JSON object data to PDF/any table format and send that data through mail. here **how i convert JSON object to PDF?**

Give me some code example,and only need client side coding (JavaScript etc).

my JSON object is as such :

```
var JSONObject= {
    "name":"Stephen",
    "street":"xxxxx", 
    "age": 25,
    "phone":"2458741"}
```

Thanks in Advance,
Stephen.L

Comment: What did you try? Where is your research result? I tried to google the expression "javascript pdf generator" and the first hit (after the advertisement of course) give me the solution...

Comment: You can use html tables for your purpose, most mail clients understand it. For mailing you can use external service like https://postmarkapp.com/

Comment: @Péter - jsPDF which i have downloaded and its working for normal text and images ... i need to give my data in JSON object to jsPDF .. how to do that?

Comment: You have to write the logic, that processing the json and use the jsPDF to generate the output.